# Can't deploy cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, google-cloud-functions

I have tried to deploy cloud functions for more than a week, but I always get an error in the log and the functions don't deploy.

I receive the following error in the log:

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Build failed: npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Missing: nodemailer@^6.6.0\nnpm ERR! \n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2021-05-13T16_38_49_151Z-debug.log; Error ID: beaf8772"}
```

This is the code of my function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("admin_sdk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://enjoylearning-a3ce3.firebaseio.com",
});

admin.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});

const db = admin.firestore();

// For Gmail, enable these:
// 1. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
// 2. https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
// For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
// auth.languageCode = 'ar';
const gmailEmail = XXXX;
const gmailPassword = XXXX;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: gmailEmail,
    pass: gmailPassword,
  },
});

// Your company name to include in the emails
// TODO: Change this to your app or company name to customize the email sent.
const APP_NAME = "EduCup";

// [START sendWelcomeEmail]
/**
 * Sends a welcome email to new user.
 */
// [START onCreateTrigger]
/* exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
// [END onCreateTrigger]
  // [START eventAttributes]
  const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
  const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.

  return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
}); */

exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{user}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const email = snap.data().userEmail; // The email of the user.
      const displayName = snap.data().userName; // The display name of the user.
      const uid = snap.data().userId;

      return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName, uid);
    });

// [END sendWelcomeEmail]

// [START onCreateTrigger]



exports.addPoints = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{user}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const invitingFriendId = snap.data().invitingFriendId;
      const newUserEmail = snap.data().userEmail;
      const invitingFriendRef = db.collection("users").doc(invitingFriendId);
      let friendEmail;

      const transaction = db.runTransaction((t) => {
        return t.get(invitingFriendRef).then((doc) => {
          // Add to the chain count
          const userData = doc.data();
          const newPoints = userData.points + 50;
          // let newCompetitionPoints = userData.competitionPoints + 50;
          let newInviteesNo = userData.inviteesNo + 1;
          // console.log("competition points is : " + newCompetitionPoints);

          /*   if(isNaN(newCompetitionPoints)||
          newCompetitionPoints == undefined ||
           newCompetitionPoints == null){
              newCompetitionPoints = Number(50);
              console.log("if called , newCompetition points is : " +
              newCompetitionPoints);
            } */


          if (isNaN(newInviteesNo)|| newInviteesNo == undefined ||
             newInviteesNo == null) {
            newInviteesNo = Number(1);
            console.log("if called , newInviteesNo is : " + newInviteesNo);
          }

          friendEmail = doc.data().userEmail;
          t.update(invitingFriendRef, {inviteesNo: newInviteesNo,
            points: newPoints});

          console.log("friend email is : " + friendEmail +
             " , new userEmail is : " + newUserEmail);
        });
      }).then((result) => {
        console.log("Transaction success!");
        return sendNewFriendAddedEmail(friendEmail, newUserEmail);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Transaction failure:", err);
        return true;
      });
    });


/*
exports.addSecondChallengerPoints = functions.firestore.document
(`challenges/{challengeId}`).onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {

const player1Score = snap.after.data().player1score;
const player1Uid = snap.after.data().player1Uid;
const player2Score = snap.after.data().player2score;
const challengeId = snap.after.data().challengeId;
const score1Added = snap.after.data().score1Added;


const drawChallengePoints = 1;
const winChallengepoints = 5;

const opponentRef = db.collection('users').doc(player1Uid);
const challengeRef = db.collection('challenges').doc(challengeId);

    let transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
  return t.get(opponentRef).then(doc => {

const noOfWins = doc.data().noOfWins;
const noOfDraws = doc.data().noOfDraws;
const noOfLoses = doc.data().noOfLoses;
const totalChallengesNo = doc.data().totalChallengesNo;
const oldPoints = doc.data().points;

console.log("player1Score : " + player1Score + " , player2Score : "
 + player2Score
  + " old points : " + oldPoints + " , totalChallengesNo : "
  + totalChallengesNo);

      if(player1Score == player2Score){
              const newPoints = oldPoints + drawChallengePoints;

              t.update(challengeRef, {"score1Added": true});
              t.update(opponentRef, {"points": newPoints});
              t.update(opponentRef,
               {"totalChallengesNo": totalChallengesNo + 1});
              t.update(opponentRef, {"noOfDraws": noOfDraws + 1});
      } else if(player1Score > player2Score){
              const newPoints = oldPoints + winChallengepoints;

              t.update(challengeRef, {"score1Added": true});
              t.update(opponentRef, {"points": newPoints});
              t.update(opponentRef, {"totalChallengesNo":
              totalChallengesNo + 1});
              t.update(opponentRef, {"noOfWins": noOfWins + 1});
      } else {
              t.update(challengeRef, {"score1Added": true});
              t.update(opponentRef, {"totalChallengesNo":
              totalChallengesNo + 1});
              t.update(opponentRef, {"noOfLoses": noOfLoses + 1});
      }
  });
}).then(result => {
  console.log('Transaction success!');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
});

return true;
});
*/

// [START sendByeEmail]
/**
 * Send an account deleted email confirmation to users
 *  who delete their accounts.
 */
/* TODO :remove this comment to add goodbye email
// [START onDeleteTrigger]
exports.sendByeEmail = functions.auth.user()
.onDelete((user) => {
// [END onDeleteTrigger]
  const email = user.email;
  const displayName = user.displayName;

  return sendGoodbyeEmail(email, displayName);
});
// [END sendByeEmail]


*/

// Sends a welcome email to the given user.
function sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName, uid) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
    to: email,
  };

  // The user subscribed to the newsletter.
  mailOptions.subject = "welcome to our app! ";
  const strtText = "Welcome to our app! We hope you enjoy it.";
  const pageLink = "To know the latest news about the app and the latest competitions please join our facebook group : \n\n https://www.facebook.com/groups/434661403874384/";
  mailOptions.text = strtText + "\n\n" + pageLink;
  // TODO : add new line instead of space
  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    return console.log("New welcome email sent to:", email);
  });
}

// Sends a welcome email to the given user.
function sendNewFriendAddedEmail(friendEmail, newUserEmail) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
    to: friendEmail,
  };

  console.log("sendNewFriendAddedEmail called");

  // The user subscribed to the newsletter.
  mailOptions.subject = "You won 50 points!";
  const strtText="We are glad to inform you that your friend whose email is \""+
   newUserEmail +"\" has registered to the app using your code and you"+
   " have got 50 points in the app."+
    " \n\nInvite more friends to get more points in our app.";
  mailOptions.text = strtText;

  /* return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    return console.log('New points email sent to:', friendEmail);
  }) */

  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    else {
      return console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
    }
  });
}
```

I tried different solutions but still, I have the error mentioned above and I still can't deploy my functions

Comment: Have you tried running `npm install` before deploying ?

Comment: You can try to exclude the lock file. How do you deploy your function? by GCLOUD CLI?